# How traffic flow to docker published port without iptables?

Tags: iptables, docker, ufw

I wanted docker to respect ufw rules, so found  this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu

I did the following:

set `"iptables": false` for docker,

set `sed -i -e 's/DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"/DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"/g' /etc/default/ufw`

set `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o docker0 -s 172.17.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE`

And it works, but I don't understand how traffic gets to the container?

Before `sudo iptables-save | grep 8123` gave me:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.5/32 -d 172.21.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8123 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER ! -i br-cf80e85bf468 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8123 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.21.0.5:8123
-A DOCKER -d 172.21.0.5/32 ! -i br-cf80e85bf468 -o br-cf80e85bf468 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8123 -j ACCEPT
```

But after I disable iptable there is no rules, how traffic comes to the docker 8123 then? Here 8123 docker published port 0.0.0.0:8123->8123/tcp

Comment: `sudo fuser 8123/tcp`?

Comment: What is your OS? Some distributions configure the `dockerd` to run communications over a different PID (`docker-proxy`) so it won't mess up with `ufw` (and that's why sometimes communications are slower for no reason). This UFW answer you're based seems to contain old info about the inner workings of docker.

Comment: @A.B `8123/tcp:             1420`

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto, I'm on ubuntu 18.04. It is confirmed that docker mess up with ufw in my case, since ufw disable rules don't make and effect. But before and after disabling iptables for docker process listening for port is docker-proxy.

Comment: 1420 is likely docker-proxy's pid which Gustavo is talking about: here in case no iptables rule handles it.

Comment: As I said, in both cases the process listening that port is docker-proxy.

Comment: Yes, either it's not used (iptables rules in place) or it's used (iptables rules not in place).